# pdf to image in nodejs lambda function

Tags: node.js, lambda, ghostscript

Trying to generate a thumbnail from the first page of pdf using Ghostscript but getting this error. my node js code is running successfully in local but in the lambda function, it is giving this error. I am using the Ghostscript lambda layer. when this error occurs?
error:

```
Error: /undefined in object
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1976   1   3   %oparray_pop   1975   1   3   %oparray_pop   1963   1   3   %oparray_pop   1817   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:731/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 8
```

code:

```
 let path = "/tmp/";
  let filePath = path + "doc.pdf";
  let imgFilePath = path + name + ".jpeg";


  //-----------------donload pdf from url and saving it to tmp directory  ---

  let pdfBuffer = await getRequest.get({
    uri: result.pdfUrl,
    encoding: null,
  });
  console.log("Writing downloaded PDF file to " + filePath + "...");
  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, pdfBuffer);


  //------checking gs version -----------
  await handleProcess(childProcess.exec("gs -version"));

  //-----converting ----------------
  var gsCommand = `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFFitPage=true -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=800 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=800 -sPageList=1 -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile="${imgFilePath}" "${filePath}"`;
  await handleProcess(childProcess.exec(gsCommand));

  //-------fetching data from tmp folder where pdf is saved
  console.log("imagepath :: ", imgFilePath);
  const data = await fs.readFileSync(`${imgFilePath}`);
  console.log("data :: ", data);
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to give us more context as to what is the cause of this error?

Comment: Are you sure what you are ending sending to Ghostscript is a PDF? "object" isn't a string you generally encounter interpreting the "internals" of a PDF. You might try replacing the call to gs with something that just stores the PDF, so you can inspect it.

Comment: edit the above question and provided the code